# YouTube API Returns Undefined In React JS Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get uploaded videos from a youtube channel playlist. The issue I am having is the YouTube API response returns undefined in Chrome's console when I console.log the response. I am using React JS, and the code below is what I have done thus far.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css'
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';

const YouTube_Playlist_Items_API = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_API_URL;
const YouTube_Key = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_API_Key;
const YouTube_Playlist_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_ID;
const YouTube_MaxResults = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Max_Results;

export async function getLatestYouTubePost(){
    const res = await fetch(`${YouTube_Playlist_Items_API}?part=snippet&maxResults=${YouTube_MaxResults}&playlistId=${YouTube_Playlist_ID}&key=${YouTube_Key}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log('data', data);
    return {
        props:{
            data
        }
    }
}

const Home = ({data}) => {
        getServerSideProps();
    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='homeBody'>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Update:

I discovered that if I remove export from getLatestYouTubePost() and call the function in the home function, the response no longer returns undefined. The code below is the updated version.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Home.css'
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Repositories
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const YouTube_Playlist_Items_API = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_API_URL;
const YouTube_Key = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_API_KEY;
const YouTube_Playlist_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_ID;
const YouTube_MaxResults = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Max_Results;

async function getLatestYouTubePost(){
    const res = await fetch(`${YouTube_Playlist_Items_API}?part=snippet&playlistId=${YouTube_Playlist_ID}&maxResults=${YouTube_MaxResults}&key=${YouTube_Key}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props: {
          data
        }
    }
}

const Home = ({data}) => {
    console.log('data', data);
    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='homeBody'>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you misspelled [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) not `playlistID`.

Comment: I corrected the issue, but the API is still not returning data. Any advice?

Comment: What `YouTube_Playlist_ID` are you trying with?

Comment: I am using PL9wYSfBCmdpYEstqliE3I0ZmtraAX_iGi as a test, but it's not pulling any data. The full link is https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9wYSfBCmdpYEstqliE3I0ZmtraAX_iGi

Comment: In my Firefox JavaScript console `(await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=10&playlistId=PL9wYSfBCmdpYEstqliE3I0ZmtraAX_iGi&key=AIzaSy...')).json()` returns 4 items as expected.

Comment: That's odd. I am not being returned anything... I know the URL is correct because I can see activity in the Google Cloud console. However, Google Chome and Firefox console does not return anything for me.

Comment: did I do the URL fetch correctly in my code above?

Comment: To be honest I don't know, I'm not keen on ReactJS, but in plain JavaScript my above code works fine, as I already stated.